# Получить доступ к wall.post в vk

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

У меня есть сайт с которого я хотел бы постить статьи в мою группу в Вконтакте. Подключение происходит нормально, выскакивает окно с подтверждениями прав, но при отправки запроса содержащего метод wall.post выдает ошибку 15(доступ к методу закрыт). Вот так выглядит запрос при авторизации

```
<a href="http://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id=<?=$vkontakteApplicationId?>&scope=offline,wall,groups&redirect_uri=http://<?=$sYourDomain?>&response_type=code">Авторизация Вконтакте</a>
```

код wall.post:

`$sRequest = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/wall.post?owner_id=$vkontakteGroupId=&from_grou‌​p=1&access_token=$vkontakteAccessToken&message=$text";`

в нем кроме сообщения я ничего не пробовал передать

Comment: А код `wall.post ` как выглядит? Что используете для публикации? Ведь сейчас `wall.post` доступен только `Standalone-приложениям` и web-приложениям, использующим окно подтверждения: `ClientAPI, OpenAPI и SDK`  https://vk.com/dev/api_confirm

Comment: В общем как я уже написал, надо использовать `ClientAPI, OpenAPI и SDK` а вы не их используете.

Comment: что кроме данного кода :
`<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({
    apiId: xxxxxxxx
  });
</script>`
должно быть на моем сайте для использования OpenAPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно совсем писал модуль для постинга в группы, поэтому отвечу. Вам необходимо создать новое приложение Standalone типа. У приложения такого типа, к сожалению, нельзя указать домен (и автоматизировать тем самым получение временных токенов доступа). Поэтому получать "вечный" токен нужно вручную.

В остальном всё как у вас:

`https://api.vk.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<?=$vkontakteApplicationId?>&scope=offline,wall,groups&redirect_uri=https://vk.com&response_type=code`

Копируете code из адресной строки, и делаете запрос на получение токена:

`https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=<?=$vkontakteApplicationId?>&client_secret=<?=$vkontakteApplicationSecret?>&redirect_uri=https://vk.com&code=<?=$code?>`

К счастью, в этом случае токен не привязан к IP адресу (в отличие от стандартной OAuth авторизации), поэтому возможно сделать эти операции через браузер, а токен прописать в своё приложение (например, в PHP скрипт, который работает с другого IP).

Answer (score 0):

Может быть Вы забыли добавить "-" (минус) перед ID группы?